# How to clip an interpolated layer in R so it does not extend past data boundaries

Tags: r, ggplot2, interpolation, contour, clip

I am trying to display a cross-section of conductivity in a lagoon environment using isolines. I have applied `interp()` and `stat_contour()` to my data, but I would like to clip the interpolated output so that it doesn't extend past my data points. This way the bathymetry of the lagoon in  the cross-section is clear. Here is the code I have used so far:

```
cond_df <- read_csv("salinity_profile.csv")

di <- interp(cond_df$stop, cond_df$depth, cond_df$conductivity, 
         xo = seq(min(cond_df$stop), max(cond_df$stop), length = 200), 
         yo = seq(min(cond_df$depth), max(cond_df$depth), length = 200))
dat_interp <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=di$x, y=di$y), z=c(di$z))

ggplot(dat_interp) +
  aes(x=x, y=y, z=z, fill=z)+
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_tile()+
  stat_contour(colour="white", size=0.25) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica")
```

Here is the output:

[interpolated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJwOI.png)

To help clarify, here is the data just as a `geom_point()` graph, and I do not want the interpolated layer going past the lower points of the graph:

```
cond_df%>%
  ggplot(mapping=aes(x=stop, y=depth, z=conductivity, fill=conductivity)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = conductivity), size = 3) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[point plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgQHi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may get better help if you provide sample data. Check out [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask the unwanted region of the plot by using `geom_ribbon`.

You will need to generate a `data.frame` with values for the max depth at each stop. Here's one somewhat inelegant way to do that:

```
# Create the empty data frame for all stops 
bathymetry <- data.frame(depth = as.numeric(NA),
                         stop = unique(cond_df$stop))

# Find the max depth for each stop
for(thisStop in bathymetry$stop){
    bathymetry[bathymetry$stop==thisStop, "depth"] <- max(cond_df[cond_df$stop==thisStop, "depth"])
}
```

Then, you can add the `geom_ribbon` as the last `geom` of your plot, like so

```
geom_ribbon(data=bathymetry, aes(x=stop, ymin=depth, ymax=max(cond_df$depth)), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```